# tkinter button destroys frame and removes index from list

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, lambda

I'm relatively new to tkinter and I'm trying to create a program to show some stock values. I have the user input the stock symbol which appends to a list of stocks and displays some information about the stock in a tkinter frame. Within the frame I have a "Remove Stock" button that I want to simultaneously remove the stock from the list of stocks and destroy that frame. Here is my relevant code:

```
current_stocks = []
stock_frames = []

def update(): #Update the Currently Displayed Frames
    print(stock_frames)
    for stock in current_stocks:
        list_index = current_stocks.index(stock)
        stock_frame = LabelFrame(root, text=stock, padx=5, pady=5)
        stock_frame.grid(row=list_index+1,column=0,columnspan=3)
        if stock_frame not in stock_frames:
            stock_frames.append(stock_frame)
        stock_info_lbl = Label(stock_frame, text=f'{stock} Current Price')
        stock_info_lbl.grid(row=0,column=0)
        graph_stock_btn = Button(stock_frame, text="Graph", command=graph_stock)
        graph_stock_btn.grid(row=0,column=1)
        remove_stock_btn = Button(stock_frame, text="Remove", command=lambda list_index=list_index: remove_stock(list_index))
        remove_stock_btn.grid(row=0,column=2)

def remove_stock(i): #Remove Stock From List and Destroy the Frame
    current_stocks.pop(i)
    stock_frames[i].destroy()
    stock_frames.pop(i)
    update()
```

I pass the list index parameter to remove stock because as far as I can see the index position of current_stocks and stock_frames should correspond to the same stock. I tried using grid_forget() instead of destroy() but that doesn't change anything. I should note that as long as I only have one stock displayed I can remove it perfectly fine, however if I add more than one stock things start breaking. This makes me believe the error has something to do with this:

```
    if stock_frame not in stock_frames:
        stock_frames.append(stock_frame)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your intuition is correct about where your problematic code lies, it is in `if stock_frame not in stock_frames`. This will always return false as this is object comparison and two `LabelFrame` are not equivalent even if they have the same text.

To get around this you would want to compare only the name in the first list (`current_stocks`) and take it for granted that `stock_frames` has an associated entry which you can delete.

the more thorough solution would be to use a more associative datastructure such as a `dict` from `stock_name --> tkinter_frame`

That would look something like this:

```py
stocks = {
  "GE": None,  # A default case
  "SYM": tkinter.LabelFrame(...), # A populated value
  ...
}
```

and your remove method would operate on that dictionary instead:

```
def remove_stock(stock_name): #Remove Stock From List and Destroy the Frame
    stock_frame = stocks[stock_name]
    # stock_frame could be None
    if stock_frame:
        stock_frames[i].destroy()
    del stocks[stock_name]
```